# deleting entire column contents on sql database

Tags: sql, database

I have a large table on an sql database and I'd like to delete the entire contents of one of the columns, What is the best practice to do that? looping over the records and set them to null would is very slow.

Comment: update very_large_table set one_of_the_columns=null

Comment: @Sergey it takes forever to do that

Comment: Do you want to keep the column?

Comment: Not really I can add the empty one later. I tried to drop the column but then it didn't free up reserved memory space

Answer (score 0):

Select [all columns except the on you don't want] INTO newtable
FROM TABLE_1;

DROP TABLE TABLE_1;
\rename the "newtable" to "TABLE_1";

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table SET column = NULL